# Pass in data parameters to new MVC ActionResult call without showing in URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, url, actionresult

I am working with adding a new MVC page and have the method and calls up and running. My issue is that I am not wanting to pass in URL parameters to show in my page but need to pass in the parameters for the method when I do a redirect to my new page. Currently I have it set up like this:

**Page.cs**

```
void ToNewPage()
{
 Response.RedirectToRoute(new { controller = "ControllerName", action = "ActionName", ID1 = 1, ID2 = 2 });
}
```

**ControllerName.cs**

```
public ActionResult ActionName(int ID1, int ID2)
    {
         ...
        return View(model);
    }
```

Currently with my code I get the URL ~/ControllerName/ActionName?ID1=1&ID2=2. I am just wanting the URL to just be ~/ControllerName/ActionName. I know this would be easier on a frontend or maybe through javascript but needing to do this from the ToNewPage method if possible.

Comment: You could create two public variables if you're having to do this from Page.cs; otherwise, I would call the action from the .cshtml file, passing it your ViewModel.

Comment: TempData or Cookie are worth considering. But honestly, querystring (i.e. what you are doing now) is the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

There are working codes:

PageController.cs

```
public class PageController : Controller
  {
      // GET: Page
      public ActionResult Index()
      {
          return View();
      }

      public ActionResult ToNewPage()
      {
          var ids = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { ID1 =  1, ID2=  2 });
          TempData["ids"] = ids;
          return RedirectToAction("Index", "NewPage");
      }
  }
```

NewPageController.cs

```
public class NewPageController : Controller
{
    // GET: NewPage
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        if (TempData["ids"] != null)
        {
            dynamic ids = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(TempData["ids"] as string);
            ViewBag.ID1 = ids.ID1;
            ViewBag.ID2 = ids.ID2;
        }
        return View();
    }
}
```

NewPage\Index.cshtml

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>NewPage</h2>
<ul>
    <li>ID1: @ViewBag.ID1</li>
    <li>ID2: @ViewBag.ID2</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use TempData:

```
void ToNewPage()
{
  TempData["ID1"]="ID1 Value"
  TempData["ID2"]="ID2 Value"
  Response.RedirectToRoute(new { controller = "ControllerName", action = "ActionName"
  });
}

public ActionResult ActionName()
{
    int ID1=int.parse(TempData["ID1"].ToString());
    int ID2=int.parse(TempData["ID2"].ToString());

    return View();
}
```

> You can fill many TempDatas in many controllers and use them in many Views and controllers